# Make different types of URLS pretty with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have two types of urls I want to make readable/pretty:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php -> www.mydomain.com/index 
(remove .php)
```

And

```
www.mydomain.com/information.php?=story1 -> www.mydomain.com/information/story1
(replace .php=? with /)
Im using $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] to grab the "story" from the database
```

I've tried for days and hours, but can't find any solutions. Any suggestions?

Comment: May you please tell us what is the expected result and actual result?

Comment: Expected result: www.mydomain.com/information/story1 - Actual result: www.mydomain.com/information.php?=story1 - I need to get rid of .php?=

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out myself.

First:
www.mydomain.com/index.php -> www.mydomain.com/index 
(remove .php)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Second:
I had to make a few changes, but heres goes:

Goal:
www.mydomain.com/information.php?story=1 -> www.mydomain.com/information/1

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^information/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)$ information.php?story=$1
```

And this is added to the php code:

```
$story_str = $_GET['story'];
$story_str = 1
```

In the  tag of your php code, add this to make sure your images and CSS is loaded:

```
<base href="/" />
```

And finally, add this to your .htaccess also to make sure your images and CSS is loaded:

```
RewriteRule ^detail/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: It's still not working. It only removes the .php and does not replace ?= with a slash / 

www.mydomain.com/information.php?=story1 -> www.mydomain.com/information?=story1 - I need it to be www.mydomain.com/information/story1 

Any other ideas? It should be possible...